# Ruby on Rails, Can i set the table alias when i join the other table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make two table aliases in my query with left join like the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u LEFT JOIN user_group AS ug
```

---

This is the current code which having any aliases.

```
@users = User.left_outer_joins(:user_group)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can

```
@users = User.joins("LEFT JOIN user_group as ug ON ug.user_id = users.id")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, have any other method to do that?

Comment: AFAIK this is the way to do manual join with alias name in rails.

Comment: we can call the method from joining table by `select users.* ,  user_group.* ...`